# Choosing the most logical order of sentences from among the given choices to construct a coherent paragraph

Tags: sentence-starts, sentence-ends, paragraphs

The sentences given below, when properly sequenced, form a coherent paragraph. Each sentence is labeled with a letter. I have to choose the most logical order of sentences from among the given choices to construct a coherent paragraph.

> (a) Similarly, turning to caste, even though being lower caste is
>   undoubtedly a separate cause of disparity, its impact is all the more
>   greater when the lower-caste families also happen to be poor.
>
> (b) Belonging to a privileged class can help a woman to overcome many
>   barriers that obstruct women from less thriving classes.
>
> (c) It is an interactive presence of these two kinds of deprivation—
>   being low class and being female— that massively impoverishes women
>   from the less privileged classes.
>
> (d) A congruence of class deprivation and gender discrimination can
>   blight the lives of poor women very severely.
>
> (e) Gender is certainly a contributor to societal inequality, but it
>   does not act independently of class.

I identified the opening sentence as ***(e)***, then I thought as the paragraph needs to be logically connected, the next one must be ***(a) Similarly, turning to caste...***. The reason is both Gender and Caste are the contributor to social inequality. But this is wrong when I saw the answer.

The correct order is ***EBDCA*** which I am not able to figure out. Kindly help me out as English is not my native lanaguage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I think there are multiple ways to order these sentences and still have the paragraph make sense (or rather: they are repetitive enough that the paragraph will be a bit awkward no matter which order you choose), but I think they want you to reason as follows:

- As you say, **E** should come first, because it's introduces the thesis, and would be redundant if it came after **B**, **C**, or **D**.
- **A** should come last, because it introduces a new variable (caste, as opposed to both gender and class) that is ignored by all the others. (It doesn't make sense to say "Similarly, turning to caste, …" and then have the next sentence turn right back to the previous topic.)
- **B** and **D** stand in contrast to each other, so one should directly precede the other: either **BD** or **DB**.
- **C** should come after **D**, since **C** implies that "being low class" is a "kind[] of deprivation" that has already been referred to, and **D** is the sentence that introduces it as such.
- So, we have two possible orderings: **EBDCA** and **EDBCA**. Of these, the ordering with **DC** is better than the ordering with **DBC**, since **C** refers directly to the topics discussed in **D** (even using the word "these", which in this case means "the just-mentioned").

So, **EBDCA** is the best ordering.

Comment: +1, thank you. I finally got it. Thank you once again for helping.